# Foundation 4, Top Bar doesn't dropdown in subdirectories

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've got the topbar working for any pages in the root directory, but when I put a page into a subdirectory, the dropdowns suddenly stop working. I've changed page styles for the main content, my guess is that the error is there, but I'm not seeing anything after searching through line-by-line for something off.

The javascripts are all pointing to the right directories, same with CSS files.

Thoughts, please?

does not work: http://www.manchester-self-store.com/arch/blog/archive-storage-and-shredding-blog.html

does work: http://www.manchester-self-store.com/arch/archives-home-test.html

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: correct the file path

Comment: Which one? All paths do appear to be correct, unless I've missed something?

Comment: This is not an issue with zurb's foundation, this is an issue in your URL, you're looking for a page that doesn't exist.